# Celery No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'

Tags: django, celery

I have this in my `/var/log/celery/w1.log`

[image]

I'm following the steps for Celery [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps).

I have this in my `celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sample.settings')

app = Celery('sample2',
            broker='amqp://',
            include=['sample2.tasks'])

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix. 
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

what can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Full document in [this link](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

you should just add the below line to `__init__.py` near settings.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

project structure

```
- proj/
  - manage.py
  - proj/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
```

Comment: Worked! Still would like to know what's happening under the hood here. Any reference to the docs or a PR solving/tackling this particular error?

Comment: @ryuzakyl
yes of course. this link explained how to config celery in Django. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: # This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)